# Userform in Excel 2013 disappears while switching an active workbook behind

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have faced one problem in Excel 2013. In my project, I have a userform that contains a listbox which lists names of all opened excel books.

When a user clicks on a particular name in the list, the appropriate book is activated. So the userform is always on top and while the user is clicking on the names in the list, he can see all opened workbooks getting activated one by one behind the active userform.

This is the way it used to work in Excel 2010.

Now, after upgrade from 2010 to 2013, if a user clicks on a name in the list, selected workbook gets activated but the userform disappears.

What exactly has been broken in Excel 2013 and what is the way to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default behavior has changed. In Pre Excel 2013, The different workbooks are shown within one main Excel window if opened in the same instance. But in Excel 2013, they are shown in their own window. And because of this a `modeless` userform will only be visible on top of the workbook that was active when the userform was loaded.

And I don't think this has a fix yet. It is by design and may not be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

@Siddharth, based on what you said, I think I have a solution.  When you open a form, it will only show up on top of the `ActiveWorkbook`.  As long as all the code is in the same code thread (not sure if terminology is right) , you're stuck with the same workbook;  But if you use the `Application.Run` or `Application.Ontime` commands it seems to start it's own code thread, which is independent enough to work.  Just `Activate` the workbook/sheet first, and then `Unload` the form and remote call the macro that showed the form in the first place.

Unfortunately, you need to use **`Unload`** instead of `Hide`, because of the aforementioned issue;  which means you need to save any/all options selected.

```
Private Sub lstFiles_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks(lstFiles.Text).Activate
    Unload Me
    Application.Run "USER_Macro1"
    'Application.OnTime Now(), "USER_Macro1"
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub USER_Macro1(Optional Control)    ' As IRibbonControl)
    ModelessForm.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

I tested it in Excel 2013 and so far it even seems to work regardless of the `Screenupdating = false` issue seen elsewhere.

Comment: Application.Run did the trick for me! (I have an .xlam add-in which shows the form on WOrkbook_Open).